# Skew-symmetric non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Do you have an example of a real skew-symmetric matrix (seen as an operator over $\mathbb{C}^n$) having at least one (purely imaginary) eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity strictly greater than the geometric one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a matrix doesn't exist. Since it is skew-symmetric, it's [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) and therefore diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Every real skew-symmetric matrix is conjugate over $\Bbb R$ to a diagonal sum of matrices of the forms $\pmatrix{0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&a\\-a&0}$ and so is diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$.